# Drawing path with FabricJS

Tags: fabricjs

First:

```
var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('c');
var path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 50 0 M 0 0 L 4 -3 M 0 0 L 4 3 z', {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    fill: false
});
canvas.add(path);
```

result:

[image]

---

So how can I rotate this arrow by 45 degree whose center point is the head of the arrow like this:

[image]

I tried to set 'originX' and 'originY', but the problem is I cannot set the origin to the head of the arrow by setting these two parameters. As shown below:

```
var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('c');
var path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 50 0 M 0 0 L 4 -3 M 0 0 L 4 3 z', {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    fill: false,
    **originX: 'left',**
    **originY: 'top'**
});
canvas.add(path);
```

[image]

```
var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('c');
var path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 50 0 M 0 0 L 4 -3 M 0 0 L 4 3 z', {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    fill: false,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    **angle: 45**
});
canvas.add(path);
```

[image]

Comment: Just an idea: Did you try 
originX: left
originY: center

as it is shown in this demo:

http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/origin.html

Comment: `originX: 'left', originY: 'top', angle: 45` should do this

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('c');
var path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 50 0 M 0 0 L 4 -3 M 0 0 L 4 3 z', {
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    fill: false,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
});
path.setAngle(45).set({ left: 100, top: 100 });
canvas.add(path);
```

Comment: OK, I will fire this bug. Thanks for your reply.